# App Crashes More on iPad 1 vs. iPad 2 due to memory: Why?

Tags: ios, ipad

In testing and production versions, my app crashes without producing any crash log (which is an out-of-memory crash, most probably) on iPad 1, but rarely (if ever) on iPad 2. The app is the same, and the iOS version is identical.

Are there any reasonable explanations for this? This happens both on iPad 1's that are 16GB (like the iPad 2's, generally) and that are 8GB.

**Note:** I realize that this question requires some speculation without seeing the codebase. I can answer questions about the code, of course, but it's not feasible to make the source available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GB rating you mention is for storage. The iPad 1 has [half the RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad#Technical_specifications) of an iPad 2, which is probably why you're seeing more crashes on the iPad 1.

Answer (score 4):

Well, its because they have different amounts of working memory.  The 16GB you are referring to is not working memory but storage memory.  iPad 2 has more working memory (Think RAM vs. harddrive space).

Comment: +1 did not know about the amounts of working memory difference. Kind of suspected that the 8 vs. 16gb issue was not relevant :)

Answer (score 3):

The original iPad only has 256Mb of RAM. The iPad 2 has 512Mb of RAM. I'm guessing you're going over 256Mb far more often than you hit the 512Mb limit.

Remember that the 8Gb/16Gb number refers to flash storage...not the amount of Random Access Memory available to applications.

Comment: doesn't it do something like swapping?

Comment: @Yar - Not that I'm aware of, no.

Comment: Thanks for this. All the answers are the same: if you don't mind, I'm going to give the accepted answer to the lowest-rep user even if he/she did shoot late. +1 and all that :)